# building roscpp

Tags: ros, catkin, libroscpp, roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All I need is roscpp libs for Android. I'm hoping there's a way I can build just these by themselves. So without knowing much about cmake, I did ...

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/ros_comm
$ cd ros_comm/ros_comm
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
```

And ended up with the following ...

```
$ cmake ..  
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0  
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0  
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc  
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done  
-- Detecting C compile features  
-- Detecting C compile features - done  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done   
-- Detecting CXX compile features  
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done  
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):  
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has  
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but  
  CMake did not find one.  

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is there a way to build just roscpp? The reason I'm doing this is that I'd eventually like to get to a point where I can modify things to start cross compiling using aarch64 tools, even if that means I have to do the port to an arm-v8a arch. The docker image for Android doesn't support the toolchains I need.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263982/building-roscpp/) by [SRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27821/srd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-15**:
Maybe have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscpp` has [a lot of necessary dependencies](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/lunar-devel/clients/roscpp/package.xml) so I don't think you would be able to build "just" roscpp.

Per Dirk's comment below, you can build by just running CMake, but you need to have your environment set up correctly. You do not need a workspace, but you do need to have ROS activated in your shell (e.g. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`). You also need to have all the necessary dependencies available. For `roscpp`, that means that you will need everything listed in the `package.xml` file. To be honest, I think the easiest way to make them available would be to just install ROS. (You wouldn't need the full ROS desktop option; the minimal install is probably enough).

If you want to cross-compile, you should start by looking here:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/CrossCompiling

You should be able to compile roscpp and its dependencies using Catkin and the cross-compilation facilities. You would then find the libraries you want in the `build` directory of your workspace, or under the directory in which you ran CMake.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-06-15**:
You can build every ROS package which uses `catkin` with a plain invocation of `cmake` without a problem. You need to have the right enironment though as well as all dependencies.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-06-16**:
I did not know that. Just goes to show, helping others is a great way to learn! I'll update my answer.